# Classification of conditions for eigenvalues of $A=\small\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to determine on what regions of a plane does the matrix $A$ have 2 negative real eigenvalues, two positive real eigenvalues, complex eigenvalue with positive real part, and negative eigenvalue with negative real part.

So I started by taking the determinant of $A$, which resulted in the equation $\lambda^2-\lambda(a+1)+(a-b)=0$. Then using quadratic formula $\lambda=\frac{(a+1)\pm\sqrt{(a+1)^2-4(a-b)}}{2} $. So focusing on the expression inside the square root, I need to find when $a^2-2a-4n+1\geq 0$ and I am not sure how to continue. Is my approach correct so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to test the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial:
$$\Delta=(a-1)^2+4b.$$
Graphically its sign depends on the position of $(a,b)$ with respect to the parabola $(a-1)^2+4b=0$: $\Delta>0$ above the parabola, $\Delta<0$ below the parabola.

When there are real roots, we know both roots have the *same sign* if $a-b>0$, *opposite signs* if $a-b<0$.

When both roots have the same sign, this sign is *positive* if $a+1>0$, *negative* if $a+1<0$. Futhermore, when the eigenvalues are complex numbers, the same conclusion is valid for their real part.

This discussion is summarised in the following graphic:

[image]

Comment: Wow how did you generate that plot, what program? Best answer!

Comment: `Pstricks` code. pstricks is a LaTeX package which defines a sort of interface between LaTeX and Adobe's `postscript` language.

Answer (score 0):

So the discriminant $d = a^2-2a+4b+1$. 
If you want real eigenvalues, $d$ must be nonnegative.

1. Two negative real values $\implies d \geq 0$ AND $a+1 \leq \sqrt{d}$.
2. Two positive real values $\implies d \geq 0$ AND $a+1 \geq \sqrt{d}$.

If you want complex eigenvalue, $d$ must be negative and you can obtain the rest of the conditions as above.